# Add column to 2d list in Dart

Tags: list, dart

I have declared a 2d list in Dart as follows:

```
int a = rows;
int b = columns;
List init_ing_quants = List.generate(a, (i) => List(b), growable: true);
```

I can add a new row to this no problem. However I am trying to add a column to each row via the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
init_ing_quants[i].add(0);
}
```

I get the error "Unsupported operation: Cannot add to a fixed-length list".

Considering the list was assigned as growable in the declaration, I'm not too sure why the error occurs and haven't had a lot of luck finding any specific info online. Any suggestions about how to achieve this/why the error occurs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your problem is not `init_ing_quants` but each list inside this list. You are creating the lists by using `List(length)` which are creating a fixed size list containing a given number of elements: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/List/List.html

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get the add columns concept to work by declaring the 2d list in a different way, as follows:

```
int a = rows;
int b = columns;

List<List<int>> init_ing_quants =
  List.generate(a, (_) => List.generate(b, (_) => 0), growable: true);
```